# Command to determine type of AIX hardware

Tags: aix

I want to know whether the given IBM -AIX box is pseries or iseries. 
If there is a command or set of commands that can give me the information for the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `prtconf` will give you more details.

```
System Model: IBM,7998-61X
Machine Serial Number: 06sd1fk
Processor Type: PowerPC_POWER6
Processor Implementation Mode: POWER 6
Processor Version: PV_6
Number Of Processors: 4
Processor Clock Speed: 4005 MHz
CPU Type: 64-bit
Kernel Type: 64-bit
LPAR Info: 1 06-5BD4A
Memory Size: 31616 MB
Good Memory Size: 31616 MB
Platform Firmware level: EA350_132
Firmware Version: IBM,EA350_132
Console Login: enable
Auto Restart: true
Full Core: false

Network Information
        Host Name: SAPIBM
        IP Address: 192.168.1.1
        Sub Netmask: 255.255.252.0
        Gateway: 192.168.1.1
        Name Server:
        Domain Name:

Paging Space Information
        Total Paging Space: 512MB
        Percent Used: 3%

Volume Groups Information
==============================================================================
==============================================================================

INSTALLED RESOURCE LIST

The following resources are installed on the machine.
+/- = Added or deleted from Resource List.
*   = Diagnostic support not available.

  Model Architecture: chrp
  Model Implementation: Multiple Processor, PCI bus

+ sys0                                                                           System Object
+ sysplanar0                                                                     System Planar
* vio0                                                                           Virtual I/O Bus
* vsa0             U7998.61X.065BD4A-V1-C0                                       LPAR Virtual Serial Adapter
* vty0             U7998.61X.065BD4A-V1-C0-L0                                    Asynchronous Terminal
* pci3             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          PCI Bus
+ fcs0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1                                    FC Adapter
+ fscsi0           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1                                    FC SCSI I/O Controller Protocol Device
* hdisk1           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-W5006048C52A8FD87-L25000000000000  EMC Symmetrix FCP Raid5
* hdisk2           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-W5006048C52A8FD87-L26000000000000  EMC Symmetrix FCP Raid5
* hdisk0           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-W5006048C52A8FD87-L0               EMC Symmetrix FCP Raid1
* hdisk30          U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-W5006048C52A8FD87-L44000000000000  EMC Symmetrix FCP Raid5
* hdiskpower0      U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-L2                                 PowerPath Device
* hdiskpower1      U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-L3                                 PowerPath Device
* hdiskpower2      U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-L4                                 PowerPath Device
* hdisk3           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-W5006048452A8FD86-L0               EMC Symmetrix FCP Raid1
* hdisk4           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T1-W5006048C52A8FD86-L0               EMC Symmetrix FCP Raid1
+ fcs1             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T2                                    FC Adapter
+ fscsi1           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C6-T2                                    FC SCSI I/O Controller Protocol Device
* pci2             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          PCI Bus
+ ati0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-C5-T1                                    Native Display Graphics Adapter
* pci1             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          PCI Bus
+ usbhc0           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          USB Host Controller (33103500)
+ usbhc1           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          USB Host Controller (33103500)
+ usbhc2           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          USB Enhanced Host Controller (3310e000)
* pci0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          PCI Bus
+ sissas0          U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T5                                       PCI-X266 Planar 3Gb SAS Adapter
* sas0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T5                                       Controller SAS Protocol
* sfwcomm0                                                                       SAS Storage Framework Comm
+ ses0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-Y1                                       SAS Enclosure Services Device
* sata0            U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T5                                       Controller SATA Protocol
* lhea0            U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1                                          Logical Host Ethernet Adapter (l-hea)
+ ent1             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T7                                       Logical Host Ethernet Port (lp-hea)
+ ent0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T6                                       Logical Host Ethernet Port (lp-hea)
+ L2cache0                                                                       L2 Cache
+ mem0                                                                           Memory
+ proc0                                                                          Processor
+ proc2                                                                          Processor
+ proc4                                                                          Processor
+ proc6                                                                          Processor
+ cd0              U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T1-L1-L2-L3                              USB DVD-ROM Drive
* kbd0             U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T2-L1                                    USB keyboard
* mouse0           U78A5.001.WIH4F4F-P1-T2-L1                                    USB mouse
```

Answer (score 4):

The most simple way to resolve this is to get the `uname` output for the machine type.

`uname -M`

and then search the web to find out what that device is.

Or, you can get that and more from AIX with,

`prtconf`

Answer (score 1):

The system architecture is queried using:

```
uname -p
```

The man page has more details in case you want different information than just the CPU architecture.